# how to run iOS enterprise app on a specific IP address

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios-enterprise

Is it possible to run iOS app on specific IP address.I have an Apple Enterprise Account and I want to distribute an app with an organization and also I want to run it on a specific IP address. 
For example, in my app I have a user authentication process. I want to authenticate only those users who come from specific IP address other than that user will not have to authenticate.

Comment: Is the authentication in-app only? Do you have a server/backend that handles auth? Do you have a way to stop that action quickly if the IP address ever changes (such as an inevitable transition to ipv6 in the future)?

Comment: You can do the authorization in your back-end server. But IP address maybe change frequently, especially when a device runs on Edge network.

Comment: @RyanCollins Yes we using a backend web api server to authenticate a user. I have no idea about IP address changing. I simply hit this url http://Local-Server/AuthenticateUser and get JSON response.